# How to preserve the new lines with Jsoup?

Tags: jsoup, lines, preserve

Is there a way to preserve the new lines , (not < BR >) with Jsoup?

```
Document pdsc = Jsoup.connect("http://drafts.bestsiteeditor.com/promoters/dsc1387266263.txt").get();
String strText = pdsc.body().ownText();

tv.setText(strText);
```

The TXT files content is from a form textarea submission that has new lines in it.
Thanks.

Comment: looks like jsoup is for HTML documents. You can probably get this txt file content using java.net api

Comment: I switched to txt with the hope to get those \n an \r just show. I made many test before with html .

Comment: apparently jsoup doesn't rely on resource name to guess it's content type

Comment: I am sure that the \n and \r\n are still in the string , but could not figure out how to match and replace them with \n or perhaps even some simpler way.?!?! thanks for your comments

Answer (score 0):

On the Document i don't think there is a method to return text that preserves new lines. if you identify the text node you want to print there is a method: getWholeText ([http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/TextNode.html#getWholeText()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/TextNode.html#getWholeText%28%29)). In case you want for the whole html you have to extract all text nodes(recursive traverse of the document). For your example (it has only one text node):

```
  Document pdsc = Jsoup.connect("http://drafts.bestsiteeditor.com/promoters/dsc1387266263.txt").get();
  System.out.println(((TextNode) pdsc.select("body").first().childNode(0)).getWholeText());
```

A more general solution:

```
private static void prinWholeText(Document doc) {
    List<TextNode> textNode = getAllTextNodes(doc);
    for(TextNode tn:textNode){
        System.out.println(tn.getWholeText());
    }
}

private static List<TextNode> getAllTextNodes(Document doc) {
    List<TextNode> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
    allTextNodes(doc, nodes);
    return nodes;
}

private static void allTextNodes(Element element,  List<TextNode> nodes) {
    for(Node child: element.childNodes()){
        if(child instanceof TextNode){
            nodes.add((TextNode) child);
        } else{
            if(child instanceof Element){
                allTextNodes((Element) child, nodes);
            }
            //implement others
        }
    }
}
```